# post route for login page is pending request in browser with express node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

The router is pending not responding (pending in request)

```
 router.post('/loginpost',(req,res,next)=>{
           var email=req.body.email;
           var password=req.body.password;
           var selectsql=`SELECT * FROM client WHERE email='${email}' AND password='${password}'`
            database.query(selectsql, (err,data)=>{
              if (data.length>0){
                req.session.email=email
              res.json({datalogin:'success'})
            res.end()
              }
         })
    
    })
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to defend yourself from.

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: You also should not call `res.end()` after calling `res.json()`.  `res.json()` already ends the response on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data.length > 0` isn't true, then you never call `res.json()` so you never send a response.

Either:

- You have an error
- The credentials you sent are wrong
- You don't have a body parsing middleware capable of handling the format of the data you are sending

You need to:

- Test for `err` in case there is an error condition
- Handle the case where isn't exactly one match (e.g. when the username and password are wrong)

and do some debugging to figure out which of the three failure states I listed above is the one you are triggering.